# app loader text while data retrieve from Firebase

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create a android app that's data available in Firebase realtimeDatabase. Now i want o add a preloader text so that visitor not fall in fault (there has no any data while it's loading). i tried this using Thread and this is ok but problem occurred when it's data loaded. After loading the app data, apps showing "UNFORTUNATELY YOUR APPLICATION IS STOPPED" (app stooping before loader text hidden).Until app data not loading, app showing the loader text but when data loaded then the loader text not hidden and application crashed. Where is the wrong?

```
package com.abdullah.md.allsimoffers;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference dref;
ListView listview;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> keyCheck = new ArrayList<>();
Bundle bundle;
String title;
private AdView adView;
private AdRequest adRequest;
TextView preloader;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    preloader = findViewById(R.id.preloaderId);

    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewId);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


    listview = findViewById(R.id.listViewId);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_layout, R.id.headingTextViewId, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {

        String intentValue = bundle.getString("intentValue");
        if (intentValue.contains("banglalink")) {
            dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://allsimoffers.firebaseio.com/banglalink");
            title = "Banglalink";
        } else if (intentValue.contains("grameenphone")) {
            dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://allsimoffers.firebaseio.com/grameenphone");
            title = "grameenPhone";
        } else if (intentValue.contains("robi")) {
            dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://allsimoffers.firebaseio.com/robi");
            title = "Robi";
        } else if (intentValue.contains("airtel")) {
            dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://allsimoffers.firebaseio.com/airtel");
            title = "Airtel";
        } else if (intentValue.contains("teletalk")) {
            dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://allsimoffers.firebaseio.com/teletalk");
            title = "Teletalk";
        }
    }




    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);


    new preloaderClass().execute();

//---------------------------onCreate method end--------------------------
}


class preloaderClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, ArrayList<String>> {



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        preloader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
                keyCheck.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                String key = (dataSnapshot.getKey());
                int valueOfKey = keyCheck.indexOf(key);
                list.set(valueOfKey, value);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.remove(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
                keyCheck.remove(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, databaseError.toException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return list;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        if (!strings.isEmpty()){
            listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            preloader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if (strings.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(strings);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.homeMenuId) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.aboutMenuId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

//---------------------options menu end--------------------------------------

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never access UI elements(e.g. preloader) from the background thread. Your application crashes due to trying access UI element, not from `main thread`. 
To fix your code, you can call

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
   preloader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
})
```

But I really encourage you to check proper ways to load data in the background to update UI from background threads. Check `AsyncTask`, `IntentService`, `ThreadPools`, `RxJava`, `Coroutines`.

Also from your code, why do you need to check `list` each time, why you can't remove preloader as soon as you create/update `list`

UPDATED: 
I don't point that you need background thread. Firebase listeners already called in main thread. Check this:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ChildEventListener {
DatabaseReference dref;
ListView listview;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> keyCheck = new ArrayList<>();
Bundle bundle;
String title;
private AdView adView;
private AdRequest adRequest;
TextView preloader;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    preloader = findViewById(R.id.preloaderId);

    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewId);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


    listview = findViewById(R.id.listViewId);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_layout, R.id.headingTextViewId, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {

        String intentValue = bundle.getString("intentValue");
        if (intentValue.contains("banglalink")) {
            dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://allsimoffers.firebaseio.com/banglalink");
            title = "Banglalink";
        } else if (intentValue.contains("grameenphone")) {
            dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://allsimoffers.firebaseio.com/grameenphone");
            title = "grameenPhone";
        } else if (intentValue.contains("robi")) {
            dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://allsimoffers.firebaseio.com/robi");
            title = "Robi";
        } else if (intentValue.contains("airtel")) {
            dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://allsimoffers.firebaseio.com/airtel");
            title = "Airtel";
        } else if (intentValue.contains("teletalk")) {
            dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://allsimoffers.firebaseio.com/teletalk");
            title = "Teletalk";
        }
    }


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);


}

@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
    keyCheck.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    String key = (dataSnapshot.getKey());
    int valueOfKey = keyCheck.indexOf(key);
    list.set(valueOfKey, value);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    list.remove(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
    keyCheck.remove(dataSnapshot.getKey());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, databaseError.toException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void updateUI() {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        preloader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        preloader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.homeMenuId) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.aboutMenuId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answare. now i used AsyncTask but still a problem. when i run the app then it is showing the loader text for infinite time. But if i opened this in second time without app close then it is showing the listview without the loading text. I am unable to understand to the reason of the problem and the way of fixing. see all code.

Comment: @Md.Abdullah `You should never access UI elements`. You can't call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from `doInBackground`. You always must interact with UI in `main` thread. But your issue that that listeners will be never called. Because `doInBackground` done its job.